# Pass the Verbose Name of Django Choices Form Field to View Context

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am building a simple order form that have many `choices` fields.  Each choices field has many options.. The form works great, it redirects to a thank you page, passing context, bills via Stripe and sends a notification email to admin.  But when I get the email with the new order, I get a dollar amount for the different choice fields, but have no idea what it belongs to without the verbose label.  Below is an example of one of my choice fields and the returned value on my thank you page.

**Heres a sample choices field**

```
MERCHANDISE_ORDER = (
    ('10000', 'Flag with 5X7 Certificate'),
    ('2000', 'MSMA Hat'),
    ('500', 'Plaque Certificate'),
    ('500', 'Flag and Plaque Certificate'),
)
```

**The template tag**

```
...
<strong>Merchandise Order:</strong> ${{ merchandise_order }} <br>
...
```

**The returned value in my thank you page and email**

```
...
Merchandise Order: $5 
...
```

As you can see, theres 4 choices so it would be great if I could get the returned value of `Merchandise Order: Plaque Certificate - $5` or something similar and verbose.

I am not using model forms and so I can control the styling, I am adding the form fields to my template manually with `{{ form.merchandise_order }}` etc..  Thank you.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. You must be using some sort of form or the last line of your question wouldn't work

Answer (score 4):

I assume you have field in model name `some_field` like this;

```
some_field = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=MERCHANDISE_ORDER)
```

You can get your verbose name from choices like this; get_**some_field**_display()

```
queryset.get_some_field_display()
```

and in template;

```
{{queryset.get_some_field_display}}
```

**You can check documentation from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display).**